# MVC Framework compatible with Aerospike

Tags: model-view-controller, orm, aerospike

I have just switched to Aerospike and am using it both as a caching as well as database layer. But the problem am facing is that I am unable to find any plugin or MVC Framework support for the same.

Would someone happen to know any Framework that supports Aerospike- language not being a constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, here:

- [ORMs for PHP](https://packagist.org/search/?q=aerospike)
- [Spikeify](https://github.com/Spikeify/spikeify) for Java

You can write the next one. Open source, man.

Comment: Thanks a tonne! I guess I'll just wait for someone to write one in nodejs! :) Really helps, appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

There are a [Aerospike cache](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-java-plugins/tree/master/play-plugins/cache-plugin) and [Aerospike session](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-java-plugins/tree/master/play-plugins/session-store-plugin) modules available for Play MVC framework that you could use.